# Many to one merge, left join in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, left-join

I was trying to do a left join between two tables `a` (4 records) and `b` (2 records). But my resultant dataset has > 8 records which is not what I expected.

The data is as follows:

### a

```
hh_id|sex|age_group|mgb|wrk_status
----------------------------------
140401100|2|10|1|1
140401100|2|10|1|1
140401100|2|10|2|1
140401100|2|10|2|1
```

### b

```
hh_id|sex__|age_group__|mgb_age
-------------------------------
140401100|3|2|36
140401100|3|2|37
```

I used the following code in python to get the following result

```
result = pd.merge(tt,tt1,on='hh_id',how='left')
```

### result

```
hh_id|sex|age_group|mgb|wrk_status|sex__|age_group__|mgb_age
------------------------------------------------------------
140401100|2|10|1|1|3|2|36
140401100|2|10|1|1|3|2|37
140401100|2|10|1|1|3|2|36
140401100|2|10|1|1|3|2|37
140401100|2|10|2|1|3|2|36
140401100|2|10|2|1|3|2|37
140401100|2|10|2|1|3|2|36
140401100|2|10|2|1|3|2|37
```

but the result I need is as follows

```
hh_id|sex|age_group|mgb|wrk_status|sex__|age_group__|mgb_age
------------------------------------------------------------
140401100|2|10|1|1|3|2|36
140401100|2|10|1|1|3|2|37
140401100|2|10|2|1|3|2|37
140401100|2|10|2|1|3|2|37
```

So ideally, the first record of `a` should take the first record of `b` and the rest of the records of `a` should take the second record of `b` and my resultant dataset should have only four records as it is a left join.

Answer (score 1):

This is a left join working [as expected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54701/how-can-the-left-join-return-more-results-than-the-unjoined-query) when the join key has more than 1 matching record in the 'right' table.

What you seem to want (assuming you meant to type `36` in one of the last 2 desired results) is to remove duplicates, which can be achieved at the start or end, by selecting the distinct results from the 'left' table, or the distinct results from the join query.

Comment: actually i'm trying to do a left join on around 1,00,000 records so I need to generalise it in such a way so that if the left dataset has 4 records and right dataset has 2 records, first record should take its corresponding recording matching the primary key which is the first record and the rest of the records should take the last observation in the right dataset

Comment: @ManideepBangaru what defines the 'first' record? In this logic the results will be different depending on which record is encountered first/how it is ordered.